# Empty list as output from scrapy response object

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping this [webpage](https://moveworks.com) and while trying to extract text from one element, I am hitting a dead end.

So the element in question is shown below in the image -
[image]

The text in this element is within the `<p>` tags inside the `<div>`. I tried extracting the text in the `scrapy` shell using the following code - `response.css("div.home-hero-blurb no-select::text").getall()`. I received an empty list as the result.

Alternatively, if I try going a bit further and reference the `<p>` tags individually, I can get the text. Why does this happen? Isn't the `<div>` a parent element and shouldn't my code extract the text?

Note - I wanted to use the `div` because I thought that'll help me get both the `<p>` tags in one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two issues here.

The first is that if you separate the class name with spaces, the css selector will understand you are looking for a child element of that name. So the correct approach is `"div.home-hero-blurb.no-select::text"` instead of `"div.home-hero-blurb no-select::text"`.

The second issue is that the text you want is inside a `p` element that is a child of that `div`. If you only select the `div`, the selector will return the text inside the `div`, but not in it's childs. Since there is also a `strong` element as child of `p`, I would suggest using a generalist approach like:

```
response.css("div.home-hero-blurb.no-select *::text").getall()
```

This should return all text from the `div` and it's descendants.

It's relevant to point out that extracting text from css selectors are a extension of the standard selectors. Scrapy mention this [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extensions-to-css-selectors).

### Edit

If you were to use XPath, this would be the equivalent expression:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="home-hero-blurb no-select"]//text()').getall()
```

Comment: so if I want to use this generalist approach using XPath how do I go about it?

Comment: @ArifKhan I edited my answer with the XPath equivalent expression. If my answer solved your issue, please accept it by clicking the checkmark.